# HTML link that downloads a zip (including when copy pasted) and redirects to a thankYouforDownloading.html page

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

On my project page, I have a button to download a zip file:

[image]

```
<a class="btn btn-lg btn-success versionedButton"
href="https://download.jboss.org/optaplanner/release/6.5.0.Final/optaplanner-distribution-6.5.0.Final.zip">
... Download ...</a>
```

Now, after pushing this button, while the zip downloads, I 'd like to **redirect the browser to another page** `thankYouforDownloading.html`.

But when scrolling over the button or copy pasting that link, it should **still be the zip file link** (not the `thankYou*.html` page).

Is this possible?

Comment: You need to add the button code. what you have tried.

Comment: I updated the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an onClick handler to the "a" element to do operation after click

```
<a href="https://download.jboss.org/optaplanner/release/6.5.0.Final/optaplanner-distribution-6.5.0.Final.zip" onClick="goToThankYouPage()" class="btn btn-lg btn-success versionedButton">... Download ...</a>
<script>
function goToThankYouPage() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        window.location.href = "download/thankYou.html";
    }, 5000);
}
</script>
```

Here is it in fiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/eyw45dgh/1/

Comment: That breaks the requirement of still having the zip link on the button (to copy paste or when hovering over as shown in the screenshot).

Comment: @GeoffreyDeSmet ok, then keep the href, I updated the answer and fiddle.

Comment: The code above works, but the 5000 is a pain: if I make it shorter, the download zip might not be downloading yet (I tried with 100 and it didn't download). Who knows how it behaves on a slow internet connection. On the other hand, 5 seconds is a long delay for the user to see the result of his/her action. So it's too long and too short too.

Comment: @GeoffreyDeSmet It worked for me (chrome) with even 1ms. But you can try another approach, The link do JUST redirection to the Thank you page, then the thank you page waits couple of seconds and do the download in pure JS, There you write the text "If download didn't start in few seconds, click here" and add the manual "a" element. I think many sites do that.